# Can I remove and append after a TableSection by specifying the name of that TableSection?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application where I frequently remove tableSections and replace them with another.  Here's the typical code I use:

- TableSection 0 - Called "Header"
- TableSection 1 - Called "Group"
- TableSection 2 - Called "Cards"

  if (tableView.Root.Count > 2)
  tableView.Root.RemoveAt(2);     // Removing section named "Cards"
  tableView.Root.Add(CreateTableSection());

I would like to make the code a bit cleaner.  Is there a way that I can remove a tableSection by using the name that I assigned to the section and also a way I can append after a named section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var header = tableView.Root.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Title == "Header");

if (header != null) {
  tableView.Root.Remove(header);
}
```

Alternately, you could just maintain a reference to the Header section when you create it, and then use that reference to remove it later.  This saves you from having to find it before removing it.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem with maintaining a reference is that the header is initially created in the XAML so I am guessing that's not possible.  But your suggestion on how to find it is perfect.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension methods for `TabelRoot` and have cleaner code.

**Extension methods**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TableSection FindSection(this TableRoot root, string title)
    {
        return root.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Title == title);
    }

    public static bool AppendAfter(this TableRoot root, string title, TableSection toBeAdded)
    {
        var section = root.FindSection(title);
        if (section != null)
        {
            var index = root.IndexOf(section);
            root.Insert(index + 1, toBeAdded);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool AppendBefore(this TableRoot root, string title, TableSection toBeAdded)
    {
        var section = root.FindSection(title);
        if (section != null)
        {
            var index = root.IndexOf(section);
            root.Insert(index, toBeAdded);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Remove(this TableRoot root, string title)
    {
        var section = root.FindSection(title);
        if (section != null)
            return root.Remove(section);
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Replace(this TableRoot root, TableSection newSection)
    {
        var section = root.FindSection(newSection?.Title);
        if (section != null)
        {
            var index = root.IndexOf(section);
            root.RemoveAt(index);
            root.Insert(index, newSection);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var root = tableView.Root;
root.Remove("Section 2");
root.AppendAfter("Section 1", toBeAdded: section4 });
root.AppendBefore("Section 2", toBeAdded: section0 });
root.AppendBefore("Section 4", toBeAdded: new TableSection { Title = "Section 3" });
```